# Can't select related category in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views

I have 2 models with custom ProductManager

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ProductManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)

class InnerCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    category = models.ForeignKey(InnerCategory, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager()
    products = ProductManager()
```

so i'm trying to get Product queryset and select related Category like so

```
queryset = Product.products.filter(
            category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug']
            ).select_related('category')

print(queryset.category)
```

and when i try to run this page i get an error

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'category'

so how can i get all my Products and Categories in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems to be correct and will fetch a subset of Products and their Categories. The query returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects) and you tried to access a non-existent attribute on it.

Depending on what you would like to do with your results, you could access them like this:

```
for product in queryset:
    print(f'{product.name} - {product.category.name}')
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, I did not understand how this method works, so I used it wrong.